# MAMP, One computer, two users, shared database

Tags: mamp

Two developers often share the same system, and both have local copies of the project and try to connect to a local database.  Both users can see the database, but tables and their data are only visible to the database's original author.

We've tried giving all permissions to both users, but it seems the only thing that works is to duplicate the database.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eww. No individual development databases? :(

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off hosting a separate MySQL instance on it's own machine, and then configure your code to connect to that database instead of the MAMP-hosted one. That being said, you will need to open the port on the firewall of the MAMP(0) for the MAMP-MySQL (usually port 8889). Then, the script on the MAMP(1) needs to be configured to connect to MAMP(0) database on the newly opened port.

You will also need to GRANT privileges for user(1) on the MAMP-host(0) database.

A connect string from MAMP(1) would look like:

```
$db_url = 'mysqli://user:password@mamp0.local:8889/es_forms_drupal';
```

Hopefully that makes some sense.